# Can I publish a book with the poems on my website?

Tags: publishing

I have posted my poems on my website. For a long time, I have been doing this. Now, can I publish a book with the same poems which I had shared on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

If you self-publish, yeah, no issue.

Via a publisher? A bit trickier, especially if you don't take down the poems from your web site first. By putting your work on the internet you've already used your [first publishing rights](https://howpublishingreallyworks.blogspot.com/2009/03/first-publication-rights.html). This makes your work less attractive to potential publishers.